# Clear the value of a lookup field on an article using some form of automation (process builder, trigger, or workflow rule)?

Tags: apex, process-builder, knowledge, lookup-filter

My org tracks update requests on our published knowledge articles in an custom object that has a lookup relationship to our articles.

When there is a new update request we edit the article and make the suggested changes. While editing the article, we also relate the article to the update request record so that during the approval process the approver can make sure that the requested update actually was made to the article.

What I would like to do is somehow clear out the value of the lookup field on the article when the article is published/approved.

Any ideas how to go about this?